# Converting a base64 string to a numpy image array changes the image output to a slightly bluer color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, flask, base64

After taking a picture with Python the outputted image turns slightly bluer than the original picture taken. How do I output the original image without the image changing to a blue like color?

The code obtains a base64 string with the data part attached. It
then takes off the data part to leave the base 64 text and then tries
to fix a binascii error. Then the base 64 string with the plain text
is converted to a numpy array.

Here is the python code I used to output the image

```py
#extract the plain base64 data text

imageuri = request.args.get('imageuri')

base64justdatatxt = re.sub(r'data\:image\/jpeg;base64,', "", imageuri)


print("original uri =" + imageuri)

print("modified string " + base64justdatatxt)


#have to convert an image uri to a numpy array, convert a base64 string to a numpy array, base64 string -> numpy array

#fixes a binascii error

image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64justdatatxt, ' /')))

#convert to numpy array

img = np.array(image)




#img = base64.b64decode(imageuri, ' /')


#cv.imwrite(fullimageurl,img)

cv.imwrite(temporary_file_path,img)
```

Comment: Please see [mcve]. If we can’t reproduce the problem it’s hard to help you fix it.

Comment: For some reason you're mixing PIL and OpenCV (each of which could do the job just fine on its own), unaware that PIL uses RGB format, OpenCV uses BGR format when reading/writing images.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I used PIL instead of OpenCV and it works correctly